# Retrofit 2 response body null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

No matter what I do the result is always null. Please help me

Api file

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("create-account")
    fun createUser(@Body accountRequest: AccountRequest): Call<ERCTServerResponse.AccountResponse>
```

Retrofit file

```
object RetrofitClient{

    val defaultOkHttpClient: OkHttpClient
        get() {
            return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()
        }

    val defaultRetrofit: Retrofit
        get() {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(defaultOkHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }


    }
```

User sign up

```
 val service = RetrofitClient.defaultRetrofit.create(ERCT::class.java)
            service.createUser(
                AccountRequest(
                    recordType = "BY",
                    accountId = 1,
                    accountCompanyId = 0,
                    accountType = "accountType",
                    accountUserName = inputUserid.Text,
                    accountMail = inputEmail.Text,
                    accountName = inputName.Text,
                    accountSurname = inputName.Text,
                    accountTitle = inputUserWork.Text,
                    accountIdtaxNumber = inputUserid.Text,
                    accountPhone = inputMobile.Text,
                    accountPassword = inputPassword.Text,
                    accountDealerId = 1,
                    accountLogin = "",
                    recStatus = "3",
                    deleteExp = "",
                    companyCity = inputSehirBolge.Text,
                    companyRegion = inputSehirBolge.Text,
                    companyTitle = inputKurumAdi.Text,
                    companyTaxOffice = "",
                    companyFax = ""
                )
            )
                .enqueue(object : Callback<ERCTServerResponse.AccountResponse> {
                  override fun onFailure(call: Call<ERCTServerResponse.AccountResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ERCTServerResponse.AccountResponse>,
                                            response: Response<ERCTServerResponse.AccountResponse>) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()&& response.body() != null) { // checks if res code is in [200..300)
                            val a = response.body()?.message
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$a" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        } else {
                            val a = response.errorBody().toString()
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$a" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }

                    }

                })

        }

    }
```

Comment: have you get the link working with some test like: curl,  https

Comment: I'm making a post method that should not be null but it returns null.

Comment: http://host.../rest/adapter/erct-service/        Yes, I got